How to change the text in TextView in activity_main.xml at anywhere of this app project?
I am developing an android app.
And there is a TextView in activity_main.xml.
How can I change the text in this TextView at anywhere(somewhere like another fragment, another activity, etc) ?

This is not something you can do directly. When an Activity is off-screen, the views inside it may or may not even exist, and when you return to an Activity, those views might be destroyed and a new Activity instance be created. Data that must be manipulated from different screens is usually handled by creating some kind of repository class that persists to disk and/or exists as a singleton at the application level. When an Activity is created, it’s onCreate() function can look at the data in the repository to decide what to put in its views.

You can change the text of an activity if your activity is active that is you are in the same activity or fragment whose parent is that activity. else as @Tenfour04 said views do not exist. Moreover you should share code snipped or something as your desired result so that people can help you better.

For that, what you have to take into account is that your frament is inside the activity where you have implemented the function to change the text.
Activity
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun setNewText(text: String) {
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title)
        textView.text = text
    }
}

Activity XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Fragment
class BlankFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        val activity = requireActivity() as MainActivity2
        activity.setNewText("New Text")

    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = BlankFragment()
    }
}

this would be an example for your solution, just put the fragment in the FragmentContainer.

This is my first time answering here so forgive me for any over/under sharing, but I actually just took a class on android development.
We know that Java is an Object-Oriented programming language, and we also know that every View in the .xml and design tab is a child of the View class (Java) that is built into Android Studio.
If you want to access the TextView from your code or another View (which is still done in the java code), you only need to create an object of the View's type (TextView in this case).
Ex:
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView's ID);
From there, you can simply say something like text.setText() to change the text from within your code or from a conditional related to some other View’s behavior.
Hope this helps!

You’re mixing up terms. A view is not a subtype of Fragment. A Fragment represents a whole screen. You cannot get a reference to another fragment using findViewById.

the findViewById will only return view when it has been drawn on the screen. Else as @Tenfour04 said in the comments of the question, it will return null and text.setText() will give NullPointerException. The OP's question is about changing text of textview that is not visible on the screen, which I don't think is possible.
